# UBUNTU 14.04/16.04 Server Boot: Dev Mount failed, falls to initramfs

Tags: shell, ssh, root, mount, ubuntu-server

When booting a virtual server with Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 (I had the issues with both), it cant find the **boot partition** for root and the system falls to the **initramfs** shell with the following error:

```
(initframs) exit
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

if I type

```
ls /dev/mapper/
```

I still can see the partition mentioned in the error (and in the GRUB)

```
root=/dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV
```

cat output as suggested in the error message

```
(initframs) cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic root=/dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV ro
```

**Notice**: it seems to mount the device in Read-Only (*ro*). Maybe I should change this after I manage to start the system...

If I type *exit* I get the same error as above.
Then I try to mount:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV
mount: can't find /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV in /etc/fstab`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem after a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04
And this actually worked!!

```
mount -o remount, rw /
lvm vgscan
lvm vgchange -a y
mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV /root
exit
```